# How to do updates on all rows at every button click

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a python app that has an admin dashboard.

There I have a button called "Update DB". 
(The app uses MySQL and SQLAlchemy)

Once it's clicked it makes an API call and gets a list of data and writes that to the DB, and if there are new records returned by the API call it adds them and does not duplicate currently existing records.

However if API call returns less items, it does not delete them.

Since I don't even have a "starting to google" point I need some guidance of what type of SQL query should my app be making.

Like once button is clicked ,it needs to go through all the rows:

- do the changes to the updated records that existed
- add new ones if there are any returned by the API call
- delete ones that API call did not return.

What is this operation called or how can I accomplish this in mysql?

Once I find out about this I'll see how can I do that in SQLAlchemy.

Comment: What you are looking for is called an UPSERT or MERGE.

Comment: "Updates on all rows" -- This is usually a sign of poor schema design.  Can the thing that is updated be stored separately?  Preferably in a single cell, not lots of rows?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set a timestamp column to the time of latest action on the table and have a background thread remove old rows as another action. I don't know of any atomic action that may perform the desired data reformation. Another option might be satisfactory is to write the replacement batch to a staging table, rename both versions (swap) and drop the old table. HTH